# Batch training in Tensorflow Slim

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am looking at [TF Slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/slim_walkthough.ipynb) introductory document and from what I understand, it only takes in one batch of image data at each run(32 images). Obviously, one wants to loop through this and train for many different batches. The intro does not cover this. How can this be done properly. I imagine there should be some way to specify a load batch function which should be called automatically when starting a batch training event, but I can't seem to find a simple example for this on the intro.

```
# Note that this may take several minutes.

import os

from datasets import flowers
from nets import inception
from preprocessing import inception_preprocessing

slim = tf.contrib.slim
image_size = inception.inception_v1.default_image_size


def get_init_fn():
    """Returns a function run by the chief worker to warm-start the training."""
    checkpoint_exclude_scopes=["InceptionV1/Logits", "InceptionV1/AuxLogits"]

    exclusions = [scope.strip() for scope in checkpoint_exclude_scopes]

    variables_to_restore = []
    for var in slim.get_model_variables():
        excluded = False
        for exclusion in exclusions:
            if var.op.name.startswith(exclusion):
                excluded = True
                break
        if not excluded:
            variables_to_restore.append(var)

    return slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
      os.path.join(checkpoints_dir, 'inception_v1.ckpt'),
      variables_to_restore)


train_dir = '/tmp/inception_finetuned/'

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

    dataset = flowers.get_split('train', flowers_data_dir)
    images, _, labels = load_batch(dataset, height=image_size, width=image_size)

    # Create the model, use the default arg scope to configure the batch norm parameters.
    with slim.arg_scope(inception.inception_v1_arg_scope()):
        logits, _ = inception.inception_v1(images, num_classes=dataset.num_classes, is_training=True)

    # Specify the loss function:
    one_hot_labels = slim.one_hot_encoding(labels, dataset.num_classes)
    slim.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits, one_hot_labels)
    total_loss = slim.losses.get_total_loss()

    # Create some summaries to visualize the training process:
    tf.scalar_summary('losses/Total Loss', total_loss)

    # Specify the optimizer and create the train op:
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
    train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer)

    # Run the training:
    final_loss = slim.learning.train(
        train_op,
        logdir=train_dir,
        init_fn=get_init_fn(),
        number_of_steps=2)


print('Finished training. Last batch loss %f' % final_loss)
```

Comment: Isn't the function load_batch undefined in the code sample u shared? I'm not familiar with your very example but I would start reading this function in order to understand the batch process.

Comment: Its given here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/slim_walkthough.ipynb     But this does nothing apart from getting a batch.

Comment: So you basically just need to iterate over batches?!

Comment: I don't think this is the correct way here because slim.learning.train also seems to take an init_function and it doesn't make sense to reinitialise for every iteration hence I believe there is more correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The `slim.learning.train` function contains a training loop, so the code you've given does in fact train on multiple batches of images.

See [here in the source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py#L793), where `train_step_fn` is called within a while loop. `train_step` (the default value of `train_step_fn`) contains the line `sess.run([train_op, global_step]...)`, which actually runs the training operation on a single batch of images.

Comment: Well, I put a print statement in the load_batch function and trained for more than 1 step and found that the load batch function was only called once so it means that the same data is being used for multiple steps hence the issue.

Comment: Further, I have not specified the load_batch function in call to learning.train, so how would it even 'know' to use this for loading new batches ?

Comment: I have done more research into this and it appears that there is a queue that gets established  from where batch is automatically loaded each time.  To test this I have a related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868871/tensorflow-slim-debugging-during-training. Please comment if possible.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the load_batch function only needs to be run once because the established queue does the work from there